# Why is margin auto not working to center a div containing links with images

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I Know this is not an uncommon question and I have tried any of the solution to pervious question That i could find

I have the following bootstrap column

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
   <div class="social-child-row">
      <a href="" ><img width="35" height="35" src="imgs/gplus2.png" alt="gplus" /></a>
      <a href="" ><img width="35" height="35" src="imgs/stackoverflow.png" alt="stackoverflow"/></a>
      <a href="" ><img width="35" height="35" src="imgs/twitter.png" alt="twitter"/></a>
      <a href="" > <img width="35" height="35" src="imgs/github.png" alt="github"/></a>
      <a href="" ><img width="35" height="35" src="imgs/email.png" alt="email"/></a>
   </div>
</div>
```

and styling:

```
.social-child-row{
    width:100%;
    margin: auto;
}
```

which results in the following

[image]

I have tried setting the width to a fixed width (200px), I have tried `display: inline`, `display: block-inline` and I have even tried wrapping the the links in a list and displaying in line. The only time Margin works is if I specify and exact size like `30px`

a JSFiddle Can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jonniedarko/9AD4d/)

some of the Code is built on top of the HTML result of [this wordpress theme](http://gentsthemes.com/demo/stanleywp/about/) in case it is relevant

Comment: Set a width like `width: 200px` (or percentage... not 100% as it cant center it) then its `margin: 0 auto;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your fiddle I imagine you're talking about `.social-child-row`?

Simply set it to `display:block;` and `text-align:center;`

It contains images which are inline elements, treated effectively like text content, as such by aligning the text for the parent to `center`, the images will be centered.

There are really two main ways of centering content:

### 1. Text Alignment (inline elements)

Set the child elements to either `display:inline` or `display:inline-block`, then set the parent container to `text-align:center`, the children will center in the parent- depending on whatever its width

### 2. Margin Alignment (block elements)

If the child content is block level (`display:block`) set `text:align:center;` on the parent, then give the child `margin:0 auto` and a **width** less than that of the parent

Answer (score 0):

You should assign width on the div you want to align on center OR you can just assign the display as `inline-block` not `block-inline` for this to work. Replace the style with:

```
.social-child-row{
    /* width: (put here for optional); */
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Use 0 margin for top and bottom since your aim only is to center horizontally in this case. `*display: inline;` and `zoom: 1;` are for earlier versions of IE compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

```
.social-child-row{
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/6K5hN/